# No signal in Smaart v9

Tags: audio, measurement

I am trying to connect my Focusrite 2i2 with a microphone to Smaart RT v9, smaart is recognising the Focusrite, but no signal. I only use 1 specific microphone to get signal. I see on the Focusrite that I have a signal from the mic, but nothing in Smaart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was a permission thing in my mac (to access the microphone). Once that was done, it worked.